# What type of Port Security is available in Android? Physical Or Logical?

Tags: android, security

I have searched a lot of but couldn't find any usefull content. I have to apply Logical or Physical port security to my application. Please guide me of when to start?

Answer (score 0):

was able to see which app had an open port using standard linux knowledge.

Install terminal emulator or do an adb shell and execute the following:

shell@android:/ $ cat /proc/net/tcp
sl local_address rem_address st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt uid timeout inode
0: 0100007F:1C23 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000 1001 0 2111 1 e22cc000 300 0 0 2 -1

The important stuff above is:

0100007F:1C23 listen IP-address:port in hex notation, here 127.0.0.1:7203
00000000:0000 remote address empty (listening)
1001 uid of the app
You can map the uid list to apps via How to know app name by UID

**Ref :**